# MySQL IFNULL not returning 0 on table with no matching records as expected

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to count the number of searches a user performed using:

```
SELECT IFNULL(COUNT(`searches`.`internalKey`),0) AS `activity`, `modUser`.`username`, `modUser`.`active`, `modUser`.`id` AS `customer_id`,`UserGroupMembers`.`user_group`, `Profile`.*, `extdata`.*
FROM `modx_users` AS `modUser`
LEFT JOIN `modx_user_attributes` `Profile` ON `modUser`.`id` = `Profile`.`internalKey`
LEFT JOIN `modx_member_groups` `UserGroupMembers` ON `modUser`.`id` = `UserGroupMembers`.`member`
LEFT JOIN `modx_gssi_user_ext_data` `extdata` ON `extdata`.`internalKey` = `modUser`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `modx_gssi_user_queries` `searches` ON `searches`.`internalKey` = `modUser`.`id`
WHERE (`UserGroupMembers`.`user_group` IN (2))
GROUP BY `searches`.`internalKey`
ORDER BY `Profile`.`fullname`;
```

If the user [identified by their internaKEy] has not performed any searches, there are no records in the modx_gssi_user_queries table & should be NULL, but the IFNULL statement does not seem to be working as I expect it to.

What am I doing wrong here.

Comment: What is it returning instead?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to `GROUP BY` a column that might be `NULL`. That's going to combine all the users that haven't performed any searches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't `GROUP BY` the column from the table that may have no matches, because that will combine all the users that have no searches into one group. Use `GROUP BY modUser.id`.